# Emulator rotation issue after updating Android SDK to rev 21 and Android Platform tools to rev 16

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-version

I have updated my Android SDk to rev 21 and SDK tools rev to 16. I created a new AVD and launched it. Now when I rotate the screen it get rotated but actual activity doen not rotates accordingly. It always display it in portrait mode.

Portrait mode Image
[image]

Landscape Mode Image:
[image]

AVD Image:
[image]

Comment: What device did you base your AVD on? What OS version is your AVD running? IOW, give us steps to try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I selected `7.0 WSGA(tablet)(1024*600: mdpi)` device with target `API 11`. I am running on `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a general problem, though it definitely seems to happen for that specific combination. Since there are no API Level 11 devices for all intents and purposes, I would suggest trying a different API level. I tried 4.0.3, and it appeared to behave better.

Comment: It is working for 4.0.3 but I am creating app for tablets in landscape mode. Is their any way to test it on API 11 - 13 as it was working in previous versions.

Comment: @Nishant: Again, there are no API Level 11 devices anymore (and fairly few 12 or 13 devices, either). You are welcome to try it with 12 and 13 -- I ran a quick test on 13 and it seemed better than 11. Also, I am not familiar with any Android 12 or 13 tablets running that resolution, though there certainly could be some. Most of the Android 3.x tablets were WXGA 10" models.